# pip with ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: python, pip, arcgis

I have `pip` installed with Python 2.7, as provided by ArcGIS Desktop 10.1. While `pip` works, it *only* works when I'm in the `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts` directory, where it's located. When I try to call it from a different directory, I get this error:

`C:\> pip
failed to create process.`

Interestingly, `pep8` (also in the `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts` directory) works fine from any directory. It seems like the `PATH` variable is working.

What's happening? This is on Windows 7, if that makes a difference.

Edit: to further clarify, I installed `pip` myself. It did not come with ArcPy. Same goes for `pep8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves I ran into this when having more than one Python folder in `PATH` and/or a wrong `PYTHONHOME` variable. Try opening a cmd shell and ensuring PATH and PYTHONHOME are clear of competing python entries and then run pip again.

```
set path=C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts
set pythonhome=C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1
pip --version
```

If that fails try upgrading/replacing pip with [get-pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip) (might have to delete pip.exe in the `Python\Scripts` folder first).

If it works you need to clean PATH so that only Python folder is in it.

If there is only one python folder look in `Windows\System32` for python files like `python27.dll` -- compare with `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1`. If there are duplicate files with different sizes and/or date stamps there's your problem.

Pro tip: use [`where`](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command to search PATH for a given executable file or dll:

```
C:\> where python*
D:\b\osgeo\bin\python.exe
D:\b\osgeo\bin\python27.dll
D:\b\osgeo\bin\pythonw.exe
C:\Windows\System32\python27.dll
C:\Windows\System32\python34.dll
```

The above system is ripe for unexpected problems. They python's don't match:

```
 Directory of c:\windows\system32

30-Jun-14  04:08 PM         3,009,536 python27.dll
18-May-14  10:45 AM         4,047,872 python34.dll

 Directory of d:\b\osgeo\bin

06-Apr-13  07:55 PM            26,624 python.exe
06-Apr-13  07:55 PM         2,448,384 python27.dll
06-Apr-13  07:55 PM            27,136 pythonw.exe
```